# ubuntu 22.04 selenium python ctrl c not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ubuntu-22.04

Selenium python script had been working in Ubuntu 18.04. Following an upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04, ctrl-c (copy) no longer copying.

code below:
This part works.(select all)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "A")

no longer working: (copy selected text)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "C")

risk_text = pyperclip.paste()
print(risk_text)
NOTE:
variable risk_text is empty (or shows previous clipboard) indicating that the selected text (ctrl-a) is not being copied.